# Writing a test suite for a Spree app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, spree

I would like to build a test suite for my Spree app using FactoryGirl and RSpec. Should I write tests from scratch, or can I somehow make use of an existing resource so I don't end up duplicating code?

There are many _spec.rb files in [spree/core/spec/models/spree](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/core/spec/models/spree). It would be great if could run `rspec spec` and run the core spree test suite plus any tests I write.

The [Spree documentation](https://github.com/spree/spree-guides/blob/master/content/developer/tutorials/testing.md) recommends running `bundle exec rake test_app` to "build the appropriate test application inside of your spec directory." When I run that command, I receive this error message:

`rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'ecommerce' (see --tasks)`

Spree is mounted in config/routes.db using this line: `mount Spree::Core::Engine, at: '/'`.

I would love to have the "appropriate files" so that I don't have to write many test that have been already written, but I am stumped. Thank you for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Spree documentation:

> Spree consists of several different gems (see the Source Code Guide for more details.) Each of these gems has its own test suite which can be found in the spec directory. Since these gems are also Rails engines, they can't really be tested in complete isolation - they need to be tested within the context of a Rails application.
>
> You can easily build such an application by using the Rake task
>   designed for this purpose, running it inside the component you want to
>   test:
>
> $ bundle exec rake test_app

In other words, if you want to test Spree itself, build a new Rails application for that specific purpose.

I doubt that is really what you want to do. If you write tests for your own application, even if it uses Spree, you don't need to test Spree itself, just the code that you write. Presumably the authors of Spree run those tests before releasing each new version into the wild.

Comment: Thank you @zetetic!! This makes sense. I do not want to test Spree itself. Here is why I wanted to write a test suite: if I write code such as additional methods or models, I want to make sure all the core Spree features still work. I am new to testing, so I would greatly appreciate if you could confirm that this is a reasonable concern or, alternatively, explain it away.

Comment: You should assume that the libraries/extensions/plugins/etc. that you use are already tested. In the case of Spree they have actually gone the extra mile and shown how to run the tests, which is a good sign. Write tests that exercise the code that *you* write. Wherever possible, use code that can be tested in small units with few dependencies. Also, write separate high-level "feature" tests that drive the entire stack.

It's wise to be concerned about problems in external libraries, but it is pointless to try to find those problems through tests. Where would you start? Where would you stop?

Comment: Got it @zetetic. With this I will go forward confidently, not worry too much about testing for the moment, and revisit these questions, and your answers, once I get more comfortable with Spree. Much appreciated!